# Doubt on a proof

Tags: integration, derivatives

I just have this doubt from my TextBook.
It is the final part of a proof that I don't understand.
$$ln\frac{N}{N_0}=-at$$I understand upto this,but they say that it directly gives this equation:
$$N=N_0e^{-at}$$
How did the above equation change to the below equation?

Comment: Apply the function $f(x)=e^x$ to both sides of the first equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the symbols make sense, it is enough to apply the inverse function of the logarithm at both sides, i.e. the exponential. You get
$$e^{\log(N/N_0)}= e^{-at}$$
but the left hand side is just $\frac{N}{N_0}$, so multiplying by $N_0$ you get
$$N = N_0e^{-at}.$$

Answer (score 2):

use that $$e^{\ln(x)}=x$$ to solve your problem